# How to logout of gmail account after logout from my app?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I have integrated sign in with google+ functionality for my application using javascript. But after the user logs out from my application, he remains logged in with gmail. It creates serious security threat. Also I am facing same problem with twitter.

Any solution is acceptable.
Thank you in advance...

Comment: So you want to clear the session from the device the user logged in? What if he was logged in to Gmail ( browsing his/her inbox), if you do same thing I think that is going to be annoying.

Comment: Thats why I m asking for a better solution

Comment: I am telling you should let the user remain logged in, unless there is a way of detecting that the user logged into your app at first if so you hv to clear the entire session, from the device if possible. that is just my opinion btw.

Comment: A user's session with social media sites and their session on your site have no relation